# Перестал работать сайт после перезагрузки сервера Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Есть сайт на Ubuntu server, на нем установлена aapanel, я пыталась устранить ошибку php и по рекомендациям в гугле удалила дефолтный файл из /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default, т.е. пересоздала его. И после перезагрузки сервера перестал открываться сайт.
В то же время в aapanel файлы находятся в папке /www/server/ и сам сайт лежит в папке /www/wwwroot/mysite.com, может ли быть такое что сервер не может слушать nginx из aapanel в /www/server/nginx/nginx.conf а пытается слушать nginx из /etc/nginx ?
Покопавшись в гугле нашла совет что нужно создать отдельный файл конфигурации с указанием пути /www/server/nginx:80 и создать символическую ссылку на /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ , потом пробовала менять сам конфиг nginx в /www/server/nginx/conf/nginx.conf и там прописала

```
server {
listen /www/server/nginx:80;
server_name mysite.com;
root /www/wwwroot/mysite.com;
index index.html;
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
}
```

и все ровно сайт даже не дышит.
Сайт работает на wordpress индексный файл на месте. Ничего не понимаю, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: помните что нужно рестартовать nginx после изменений?